# How to read file path in php

Tags: php, html

I am looking for file path store in local system for eg. when I select file and post to another page then I Just want it's real path.

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Select File: <input type="file"  name="file"> 

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File!" /> 

 </form>
```

I know how to upload file but I don't wan't to upload file  Just want to read path of that selected file for Eg.

```
C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Koala.jpg
```

Actually I am working on Exeoutput for PHP 2 it's running on local server so when user upload file it's not support file upload so am trying to store file path for image upload , so when ever program will start so selected image will autoamtically will show

```
   <img href='C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Koala.jpg'/‌​>
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want `dirname()`?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php Or `realpath()`?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: Could you provide an MCVE? I don't understand what you're getting at here.

Comment: Please explain better, this has little to no context or explanation, and is confusing for those trying to answer (like myself)

Comment: It's hard to understand but it seems he is posting a file from a page to another one and would like to get the full (absolute) path of the file. If this is what you want, you will not be able to do it. Unless using a JS library, maybe...

Comment: You want the "real path" on the client's computer?

Comment: actually i am working on exeoutput for PHP 2 it's running on local server so when user upload file it's not support file upload so am trying to store file path for image upload , so when ever program will start so selected image will autoamtically will show `<img href='C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Koala.jpg'/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

File inputs are designed to upload files.

For security reasons, they conceal information about where exactly the file came from. In the context of the WWW, it should not matter to the server where the user kept the file on their computer.

Even though you are using an HTTP server and web browser in a non-WWW content, you can't override these security features.